# Should I mutate a type or create a new one

Tags: c++

If I have a `Base` type, which holds some `Metadata` and needs to be binded to a `Data*`. The `Metadata` is useless after binding happens. Should I:

1. Mutate the type with some kind of method, and have it hold both the `Metadata` and bound `Data*`:

```
class Base
{
public:
    bool TryBind()
    {
        m_Data = TryBindMetadata(m_Metadata); // Function that returns a Data*

        if (!m_Data)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

private:
    Metadata m_Metadata;
    Data* m_Data{};
};
```

2. Split it into two types, one holding the `Metadata`, and  the other holding the bound `Data*`

```
class Base
{
public:
    BoundBase* TryBind()
    {
        return TryBindMetadata(m_Metadata); // Function that returns a BoundBase*
    }

private:
    Metadata m_Metadata;
};

class BoundBase
{
public:
    BoundBase(Data* data) : m_Data{ data }
    {
    }

private:
    Data* m_Data;
};
```

Why should I choose one over the other? What are the benefits of one over the other?

Comment: Treading very close to Opinion Based.  Can you reword ?  If both approaches work (for you) we can only offer opinions.

Comment: @RichardCritten guess you're right this is probably opinion based, I don't think I can reword it much, I just don't know if there are any advantages to one or the other.

Comment: All I can add is - I think the OOP _"Single Responsibility Principle"_ should probably be the deciding factor (in my opinion) ie 1 class, 1 job.

Comment: Not really enough information on what data is to have an opinion, but I'm guessing tryBind is returning heap memory. Looks like a memory leak waiting to happen, and maybe a misunderstanding of how polymorphism works. I.e. it could be set in the Bases constructor, m_Data could be protected so all child objects can access/populate it directly, etc

Comment: @Natio2 nooo this is not actually real code, its just the idea behind it, i use smart pointers in the actual code

Comment: How about the second case but with only a move constructor. Because then the metadata is actively useless, as in you CAN NOT legally use it after.

Comment: I also think that as currently written the question is 100% opinion-based. However, you might want to formulate the **goal** you are trying to achieve and ask how to do that. That would be more on-topic.

Comment: Regarding the question: I think you should ask yourself what the datatype represents. Without more context, it seems you have two different datatypes (one contains information required to bind something, the other contains information about the bounded thing), so it should really be two different types. However, maybe the class represents something bigger, like the state of a connection object, in which case it could have some members that are not always defined/necessary. As long as the code is clear and maintainable, that's totally fine, IMHO.

Comment: @wovano thanks for the suggestion, will do next time

Comment: @wovano and yes you are right, it was the first case, i made a second type, it logically makes more sense in my context